# Vanilla JavaScript-Selecting DOM elements using a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to select a DOM element using a javascript function (i want to know HOW to do this so don't tell me "Just use JQuery")

this is my JS:

```
function Obj(a, b, c, d, e) {
    c = a.charAt(0);
    d = a.substring(1);
    if (c == ".") {
        e = document.getElementsByClassName(d)[b];
    } else {
        if (c == "#") {
            e = document.getElementById(d);
        } else {
            e = document.getElementsByTagName(a)[b];
        }
    }
    return e;
}

function change(){

    var variable=Obj(".foo",1)
    variable.style.height="100px"

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">something</div>
<div class="bar">something</div>
<div class="foo">test</div>
<div class="bar">something</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuB89/)

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Why can't you use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) / [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)?

Comment: Why are you overwriting the function parameters `c`, `d`, and `e`? It looks like these should be declared as local variables, not parameters.

Comment: @Barmar: That's how he's declaring variables. For minification purposes…

Comment: If you want help with your code, don't post it in minified form.

Comment: @SeanVieira I was not aware of that, thanks

Comment: @Barmar http://jsfiddle.net/rM4Q6/1/ better?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because your problem seems to have been solved by simply *calling* the function you defined, that you thought wasn't working.

Comment: @siabaJS No, not better. Local variables should be declared with `var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me, are you calling your change() function? When I call that, it does what I expect it to do... Modifies the 2nd item of .foo class.

Try adding change(); at the bottom of your fiddle.

```
change();
```

[Forked Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rM4Q6/)